# OFFSET sample id excel

Tags: excel, match, offset, helper

Im currently working on an excel sheet for my company, the model im being tasked to work in lookes like this: 
[image]

Im trying to make a match index from using col E and col G to fill out col H, my idea is to use F as a hidden helper col so im typing in one sample ID in col E and then 7 rows in col F will fill out with the same sample ID and then the match index would be kinda straight forward, I have a vague idea that using OFFSET is the way to go but i cannot get it working... Does anyone have an idea of how to get the OFFSET formular to work or maybe another idea as to how i can get this working?

Comment: Have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28180906/4961700

Comment: I can't see the image from my work, but looks like a job for `INDEX()`. Also keep in mind, if you have lots of data, that `OFFSET()` is *volatile* while `INDEX()` is not. This can make a big difference.

Comment: @SolarMike your link is about Google spreadsheet. AFAIK `UNIQUE()` does not exist in Excel.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez true, oops... But there are **many** other Q and A showing the use of index with match...

Comment: Try this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46886998/4961700